# hidden class can be edited using console window. how to prevent someone to do this?

Tags: javascript, html, security

[image: HTML for type=hidden input in dev tools]

Here class="hidden" can be removed and functionality of change password can be called. how to prevent someone to hack this functionality ?

Comment: You can't, not possible. You must enforce on the sever.

Comment: For things like this, where you don't want users to simply be able to toggle the hidden status, you may want to create it programmatically when needed, and destroy it immediately when its usefulness is served. If you wanted to add a layer of 'protection', have your page fetch the JS to create the change password from the server, rather than having in embedded in the page.

Comment: Instead of serving the client the data of a web page, you need to load the web page onto a locked-down browser, installed on a physically-sealed computer and then physically send that computer to the user via postal mail. (All joking aside, this isn't possible: your web page is just data. Computers are machines built for manipulating data!)